# Show images in GridView (loaded from URLs stored in SQL database)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm very new to ASP.NET and C# and I would need a help here.

**My task:**

I would like to show images in Grid View from particular URLS. I'm keeping those URLs in my SQL database, but they are NOT complete. What I mean by this:

URL in my database looks like this: "somefolder/imagename.jpg" (without quotes). I would like to concatinate URL from database with my starting url, for example: "www.mypage.com/somefolder/imagename.jpg" and everything show in GridView.

How to start with this particular task? Any help really appriciated.

Comment: What are you using to display image in your grid? Image fields or html image tag?

Comment: Actually nothing yet. I just heard , that I should use GridView for this task. Anything more is beyond my scope. I have mobile app which shows images from database, and I would like to do on website also, but I'm not that much familiar with ASP.NET. Sorry. So Any advice woudl be appriciated :)

Comment: [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bind-image-in-gridview-f88fc0f7) This should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ImageField` and use the format string attribute to format how the url is formed in relation to the value in the database. The {0} is placeholder for the value coming from the database and will be substituted when the gridview is generated

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="xxx" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>

    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlFormatString="http://mysite/{0}" DataImageUrlField="url">
    </asp:ImageField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```